# Good resources to explain Java VM non-standard options

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I would like to know if there are any good resources (online or books) that explain the Java VM non-standard options.

And by explain, I don't mean just saying what an option does, but also provide guidelines/examples on when it should be used to improve application performance.

Comment: Unless you have a specific problem you shouldn't use them.  You should be able to run Java without any non-standard options efficiently, unless you know something about your application which is unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know of books, [Java Performance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137142528) is the most comprehensive recent book (look at Chapter 7).

Answer (score 2):

Please go through [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) post this is Oracle's VM specification ,maybe this is helpful to you.

[Java SE 6 HotSpot[tm] Virtual Machine Tuning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html)